# Messed with SystemParametersInfo and Booleans pvParam parameter

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, api, winapi

I'm trying to use `SystemParametersInfo` function to set a Boolean parameter, this is just an example of one of the Booleans parameters that I will set:

```
' I try to set a boolean parameter, but no matter if I use False or True, 
' the parameter on the SO is always activated.
SystemParametersInfo(SPI.SPI_SETCURSORSHADOW, 0UI, False, SPIF.None)

' I check the modified parameter but always is positive.
Dim MyBoolean As Boolean = False
SystemParametersInfo(SPI.SPI_GETCURSORSHADOW, 0UI, MyBoolean, SPIF.None)

MsgBox(MyBoolean) ' Always is 'True', 
' and in the Advanced properties of the SO;
' the 'Show shadow under mouse' option is always checked.
```

And this is other example:

```
' Enable Accelerator Keys Visibility ( The underlined keys of the ContextMenu )
NativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo(SPI.SPI_SETKEYBOARDCUES, 0UI, True, SPIF.None)
```

The documentation for both in MSDN says to use a False boolean to disable the parameter:

```
''' <summary>
''' Enables or disables a shadow around the cursor. 
''' The pvParam parameter is a BOOL variable. 
''' Set pvParam to TRUE to enable the shadow or FALSE to disable the shadow. 
''' This effect appears only if the system has a color depth of more than 256 colors.
''' Windows NT, Windows Me/98/95:  This value is not supported.
''' </summary>
```

But the truth is that I can't find the way to Disable them once they are enabled, I've tried to use directly a boolean value, also with a boolean variable, and with combinations of the SPIF parameter, no way, if I activate a parameter I can't turn it off, I supose that I'm doing something wrong but ...what is?.

PS: I'm using Windows 8 x64

And this is the `SystemParametersInfo` part:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Friend Shared Function SystemParametersInfo(
              ByVal uiAction As SPI,
              ByVal uiParam As UInteger,
              ByRef pvParam As Boolean,
              ByVal fWinIni As SPIF
) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

<Description("SPI System-wide parameter - Used in SystemParametersInfo function")>
Public Enum SPI As UInteger

    SPI_SETKEYBOARDCUES = &H100B
    SPI_GETCURSORSHADOW = &H101A
    SPI_SETCURSORSHADOW = &H101B

End Enum

<Description("SPIF System-wide parameter - Used in SystemParametersInfo function")>
<Flags>
Enum SPIF

    ''' <summary>
    ''' None
    ''' </summary>
    None = &H0

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Writes the new system-wide parameter setting to the user profile.
    ''' </summary>
    SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = &H1

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Broadcasts the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message after updating the user profile.
    ''' </summary>
    SPIF_SENDCHANGE = &H2

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Same as SPIF_SENDCHANGE.
    ''' </summary>
    SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = &H2

End Enum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Win32 API stuff tends to be geared for C/C++ where True is 1 (or actually just not zero IIRC).  You need to change MyBoolean to `Integer` and use 0 or 1.  You'll also have to change the API signature:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
 Private Shared Sub SystemParametersInfo(uiAction As UInteger, 
       uiParam As UInteger, ByRef pvParam As Integer, fWinIni As UInteger)

 End Sub
```

This is also why you saw 0 and 1 and the return for many, many of those WndProc messages you were messing with.  Its the T/F return whether the message was handled in many cases.

Comment: thanks, but I've did all what you've said and I still can't turn the values OFF (false). PS: I'm using your signature to test this but the 'Sub' statement is right? I have like other 10 signatures and all are funcs

Comment: you can change it to a function if you want.  the returns rarely seem to comply with the documentation though.

Comment: I just changed the Byref to Byval and worked! but this is good idea to keep it as byval? (I know the difference but what I don't understand is why the function changes the boolean value to 1 when ByRef if I'm trying to set it to 0)

Comment: I may have typed it wrong (was looking at my long, long list of them), but PInvoke has it as byRef, but as long as it works....  This might be one of those things that you are supposed to set before the app message pumps starts.  That is, call it before `Application.Run`

Comment: Please see ~> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099943/conflict-with-systemparametersinfo-signatures

Comment: yea, i was still typing when the other answer popped up