# Conflict with SystemParametersInfo signatures

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, pass-by-reference, signature

Simply as this, to run this instruction:

```
NativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo(SPI.SPI_SETKEYBOARDCUES, 
                                   0UI, 
                                   True, 
                                   SPIF.None)
```

I need this signature:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Sub SystemParametersInfo(
               ByVal uiAction As NativeMethods.SPI,
               ByVal uiParam As UInteger,
               ByVal pvParam As Boolean,
               ByVal fWinIni As NativeMethods.SPIF)

End Sub
```

But to run this other instruction:

```
Dim MyBoolean As Boolean = False
NativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo(SPI.SPI_GETKEYBOARDCUES, 
                                   0UI, 
                                   MyBoolean, 
                                   SPIF.None)
```

...Of course I need to ByRef the Boolean parameter to retrieve the value:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Sub SystemParametersInfo(
               ByVal uiAction As NativeMethods.SPI,
               ByVal uiParam As UInteger,
               ByRef pvParam As Boolean,
               ByVal fWinIni As NativeMethods.SPIF)

End Sub
```

So how I need to manage those signatures? I can't just choose one.

There is a way to keep both signatures as Boolean to don't change one of them to Integer?

And yes the first instruction don't works with a ByRef parameter, then how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you would declare both versions as overloaded methods. And then let the compiler select the appropriate one depending on whether you pass the parameter by value or by ref. However, VB syntax does not allow you to specify whether the parameter is by ref or by value. In C# you have to include `ref` or `out` and so the overload resolver can use that information to pick the appropriate method.

I think this means that you need to define two methods with different names. For instance:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SystemParametersInfo")>
Private Shared Sub SystemParametersInfoByValBoolean(
               ByVal uiAction As NativeMethods.SPI,
               ByVal uiParam As UInteger,
               ByVal pvParam As Boolean,
               ByVal fWinIni As NativeMethods.SPIF)

End Sub

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SystemParametersInfo")>
Private Shared Sub SystemParametersInfoByRefBoolean(
               ByVal uiAction As NativeMethods.SPI,
               ByVal uiParam As UInteger,
               ByRef pvParam As Boolean,
               ByVal fWinIni As NativeMethods.SPIF)

End Sub
```

Comment: @ElektroStudios I just fixed it. I'm not fluent in VB so I got the syntax wrong.

Comment: no problem, thankyou it works as expected and I've learned this interesting thing

Comment: @ElektroStudios  VB also supports the old ALIAS keyword: `Declare Function getUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (
  ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByRef nSize As Integer) As Integer`  `Declare` and `DLLImport` being interchangeable but the later is preferred because of the other options it affords.  Edit: lots of info! http://stackoverflow.com/a/8793709/1070452