# SPI_GETCURSORSHADOW 0x101A - Trouble getting the boolean

Tags: powershell

Here's the PowerShell code at the bottom that I've tried to write but failed to retrieve the cursor shadow state.

I've looked at the help here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow

**And it states that:**

> SPI_GETCURSORSHADOW 0x101A
>
> Determines whether the cursor has a shadow around it. The pvParam parameter must point to a BOOL variable that receives TRUE if the shadow is enabled, FALSE if it is disabled. This effect appears only if the system has a color depth of more than 256 colors.

**My code attempt which can be saved as a .ps1 file and tested in PS ISE**

```
$CSharpSig = @'
  [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
  public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
      int uiAction, uint uiParam, uint pvParam, uint fWinIni);
'@

$SPI_GETCURSORSHADOW = 0x101A

$CursorRefresh = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $CSharpSig -Name WinAPICall -Namespace SystemParamInfo -PassThru

# SPI_GETCURSORSHADOW - pvParam 0 or 1 (3rd argument)
$CursorRefresh::SystemParametersInfo($SPI_GETCURSORSHADOW, 0, $BOOLTOGGLE, 0)
write-output $BOOLTOGGLE
```

This returns `False` as the state all the time even though that is not the case.

I'm at a loss how to get this even after reading a similar thread which is not directly associated with PowerShell:
[Messed with SystemParametersInfo and Booleans pvParam parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099025/messed-with-systemparametersinfo-and-booleans-pvparam-parameter)

---

**Edit, new issue:**

My full intention for the code was to try toggle the setting for the shadow of the cursor so here's my latest attempt to do so. I've put the comments relating to the problem inside the code.

This code works for my initial problem but not when I add back in the commented code at the bottom.

```
# More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow

# Get the original setting
$CSharpSigGet = @'
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
      int uiAction, uint uiParam, out bool pvParam, uint fWinIni);
'@
$SPI_GETCURSORSHADOW = 0x101A
$CursorGet = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $CSharpSigGet -Name WinAPICall -Namespace SystemParamInfo -PassThru
[bool] $getBool = $false
$CursorGet::SystemParametersInfo($SPI_GETCURSORSHADOW, 0, [ref] $getBool, 0).value # Stores the boolean.
$cursorShadowBool = ([ref] $getBool).value
write-output $cursorShadowBool

# Toggle the original setting
# This code is now not working as it throws an error when this code below is uncommented..
# Error below:
# TYPE_ALREADY_EXISTS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

# $SPI_SETCURSORSHADOW = 0x101B
# $CSharpSigSet = @'
#   [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
#   public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
#       int uiAction, uint uiParam, uint pvParam, uint fWinIni);
# '@
# $CursorSet = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $CSharpSigSet -Name WinAPICall -Namespace SystemParamInfo -PassThru
# $CursorSet::SystemParametersInfo($SPI_SETCURSORSHADOW, 0, -not ([ref] $getBool).value, 0)
```

Comment: Yeah, please don't do that -- restrict questions to one issue at a time. Tacking on a new problem when an accepted answer is already present is especially counterproductive, since few people will look at it. While closely related, your new problem does have a different cause and a different solution and should be discoverable as a new question.

Comment: I thought I'd add it. There's no harm in that. I will post a new question if I cannot find the answer. I thought seeing as your answer didn't fully work as it was missing `add-in` and the `$SPI_GETCURSORSHADOW` variable, I wanted to post the final solution.

Comment: Well yes, I did leave out the bits that didn't need to be modified since I figured you (and any future readers) would be smart enough to see how that worked. Code that's going to be able to both get and set the parameter is going to be structured quite differently, though, and I'm not going to modify the existing answer to include that as it wouldn't even match the original title anymore, let alone the original problem.

Comment: I just thought I'd add it as new users or coders would struggle a bit. I might read the registry and get the boolean that way and use my existing code to set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa):

> SPI_GETCURSORSHADOW 0x101A
>
> Determines whether the cursor has a shadow around it. The `pvParam`
>   parameter must point to a `BOOL` variable that receives `TRUE` if the
>   shadow is enabled, `FALSE` if it is disabled. This effect appears only
>   if the system has a color depth of more than 256 colors.

So your signature is incorrect; the third parameter must *point* to a `BOOL`. Assuming you only need to call it for this specific case and we don't need to bother with a generic `IntPtr`:

```
$CSharpSig = @'
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
      int uiAction, uint uiParam, out bool pvParam, uint fWinIni);
'@

[bool] $BOOLTOGGLE = $false
if ($CursorRefresh::SystemParametersInfo($SPI_GETCURSORSHADOW, 0, [ref] $BOOLTOGGLE, 0)) {
    write-output $BOOLTOGGLE
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question but now there's an error when I try to add the toggle ability to the code. `TYPE_ALREADY_EXISTS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand` I've searched on here and there's plenty of posts but I couldn't get them working. I'll post me up to date code below the question but in the meantime I'll keep trying to find the problem.

Comment: @StephenSherry Keep in mind that compiled types become part of the session. You can only do your little `Add-Type` dance *once*. Either restart the session, or (if you're adding more methods for some reason) rewrite the code so that you add one class with multiple methods. (Or use different names, if you really want, but that would get clumsy.)

Comment: Thanks, that's all new to me. I was really hoping that wasn't the case. My whole intention was to toggle the setting. I've posted my working code in the OP with the addition of my new problem.